# object[] as a datagridview datasource

Tags: c#, data-binding, object, orm, datagridview

My Telerik OpenAccess ORM mapped and executes a stored procedure for me which returns an array of object[] as the result.

Now i want to bind this result to my datagridview which has 4 columns setup, but i'm having a hard time doing this.

Which would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I have not used a DataGridView control in a while, but know that you can bind to array items as follows: `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridView just bound to your object's property.

So , you can convert your object[] to let your datagridview can read.

```
            var datasource = from p in (object[])
                             select new
                             {
                                 Column1 = p.GetType().GetProperty("property1").GetValue(p, null),
                                 Column2 = p.GetType().GetProperty("property2").GetValue(p, null),
                                 Column3 = p.GetType().GetProperty("property3").GetValue(p, null),
                                 Column4 = p.GetType().GetProperty("property4").GetValue(p, null),
                             };


            dataGridView1.DataSource = datasource;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Column1";

            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Column2";

            dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Column3";

            dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Column4";
```

Comment: But, for this my columns have to have a name, like property1, property2, right? The problem is that there are no column/property names. It's just a object[] with object[]'s.

Comment: Can you tell me about your object structure?  number ? string ?  or custom class ?

Comment: The objects contain some number and some string values. No custom classes.

Comment: var datasource = from p in {"1" , 1 ,2 ,3 ,"sss"}  select new { Name = p }    ; So ,you have your custom class with property is Name ... you just need bind Name to your GridView

Comment: This helped me with a datasource conversion issue. Thanks alot!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `DataGridView` control (as with other controls which support data-binding in Windows Forms) cannot accept an `object[]` as its data source. Although it will not raise an exception, it will not be able to discover the properties/columns via reflection, as each item in the array is simply of type `object`. You need to copy the elements of the array into a strongly-typed list or, alternatively, a non-generic collection like `ArrayList` (which uses different logic to discover the properties of its elements) and bind to this new collection.